# How to make image from BufferImage

Tags: java, swing, file-io, bufferedimage, imageicon

I am trying to make image from BufferImage, but it's not working. here is my code ...

This code is not working, can anyone please help me ...

```
try {

       BufferedImage bimage = (BufferedImage)(new ImageIcon("str")).getImage();

       BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, bimage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
       File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
       ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile); 
       Image image_1  = ImageIO.read(new File("saved.png"));

       lp2_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image_1));

   } catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: what is your output or what is the error?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'it's not working'? Is there a compile time error? A run time exception? What is the exception and stack trace and message if so? Is there a logic error?

Comment: if you are working in windows then change this line

Image image_1  = ImageIO.read(new File("saved.png"));


to 

Image image_1  = ImageIO.read(new File("d:\\saved.png"));

and you will get the image,

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871307/jframe-not-showing-a-picture/13871588#13871588) which loads a image from a file and paints onto a panel.  Also take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: How are you compiling the program ? How can you cast an [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) to a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) using `BufferedImage bimage = (BufferedImage)(new ImageIcon("str")).getImage();`, isn't the compiler stopping you here itself ? Had you tried adding `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch block ? You must be getting some sort of an exception, which you not looking at (something like cannot cast Image to BufferedImage)

Comment: Instead you can do like this : `image.createGraphics().drawImage(youImageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);`. Moreover, always try to refer to static fields with class Names like `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` instead of using objects like you doing in your code snippet :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw: I am not able to get your point sir ... What I want to do is  take an image from a JPanel convert it to Gray-scale and then Display it on other JPanel ...

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/1057230) by @AndrewThompson, might can help you a bit more on the topic and this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11272938/1057230), I hope :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your way of converting `IconImage` to `BufferedImage`is not right.

So you can try the following snippet

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
// paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
g.dispose();
```

After this you can use `BufferdImage` as you are already using.

Or you can look this question [Java converting Image to BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605248/java-converting-image-to-bufferedimage)
if you want to see how to convert `Image` to 'BifferedImage' because as given in this post you can't just cast `Image` to `BufferedImage`.

Although i would request you to add more information like what error or exception you are getting and may be if there is an exception add the stacktrace .

Comment: @AbhilashGOyal does the image that you want to add to `JPanel` already exists on the disk ?

Comment: kaysush: actually, I am saving this image from BufferImage on disk and then reading this image from disk

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will work better, I have tried it many times.

```
public void writeImage(String output, String fileName, BufferedImage img) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(output + "\\HE\\" + fileName + ".bmp");
        ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", file);
}
```

=================================================================================

If you want to use this image in any JPanel then here is code for it, it is already working fine,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ShowImage {


    public ShowImage(final String filename) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JFrame editorFrame = new JFrame("My Frame " +filename);
                editorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);      
                BufferedImage image = null;
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
                JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
                jLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
                editorFrame.getContentPane().add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                editorFrame.pack();
                editorFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                editorFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working Image image_1 = ImageIO.read(new File("d:\\saved.png"));

Comment: @AbhilashGoyal, Goyal sahab, refer my code, i have used it more than 1000 times, it is ERROR free, :)

Answer (score 1):

here is my new code and its working properly ... thank you all for your kind support ...

try{

```
       BufferedImage cat = ImageIO.read(new File(str));

       for (int w = 0; w < cat.getWidth(); w++) {
       for (int h = 0; h < cat.getHeight(); h++) {
           Color color = new Color(cat.getRGB(w, h));
           //int averageColor = ((color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3);
           //int averageColor = int((color.getRed())*0.21 +(color.getGreen())*0.71+(color.getBlue())*0.07);

           double r =color.getRed()*0.21;
           double g =color.getGreen()*0.71;
           double b =color.getBlue()*0.07;
           int averageColor = (int)(r+g+b);

           Color avg = new Color(averageColor, averageColor, averageColor);
           cat.setRGB(w, h, avg.getRGB());
                                               }
                                               }
           ImageIO.write(cat, "jpg", new File("image_greyscale.jpg"));
           lp2_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon((new ImageIcon("image_greyscale.jpg")).getImage().getScaledInstance( 600, 600,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

       }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here missed the point.  [A `BufferedImage` is an `Image`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)