# Java: Image Not Displaying

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am making a program where I need to display an image. I am using the ImageIcon and Image classes in order to do this. I declared the ImageIcon in the constuctor and then assigned the images value through i.getImage(). Everything but the image seems to be loading fine. Here is my code:

UPDATE: I have the image in the same directory as the code. I am using a mac and I have tried "image.png", "./image.png", "Users/myStuff/Documents/workspace/Game/src/image.png". Niether of these have worked.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JFrame {

    int x = 100, y = 100;

    private Image dbimage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    Image image;

    class AL extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
                if (x <= 20) {
                    x = 20;
                } else {
                    x -= 5;
                }
            } else if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                if (x >= 230) {
                    x = 230;
                } else {
                    x += 5;
                }
            } else if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                if (y <= 20) {
                    y = 20;
                } else {
                    y -= 5;
                }
            } else if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                if (y >= 230) {
                    y = 230;
                } else {
                    y += 5;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public Game() {

        //load up image
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("image.png");
        image = i.getImage();

        //set up properties
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setTitle("Game");
        setSize(250, 250);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbimage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbimage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbimage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 30));
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g.drawString("Hello World!", 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.RED); 
        g.drawImage(image, 100, 100, this);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on where you place your images. So make sure you place and use the correct location.

Comment: Yep, correct path to the image is where I'd start. So debug this in the most simple program possible -- showing an ImageIcon in a JOptionPane. You also should look at similar questions no this site, as you're drawing your image all wrong, including trying to draw it directly within the JFrame. Every tutorial, and any decent answer on this site will tell you never to do this.

Comment: For a list of similar questions, look to the list of related questions to the right, and also look at [this Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jframe+image+not+displayed+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the image is a file on the disk and not an embedded resource within the application context.  Consider using `ImageIO.read`. Swing components are also double buffered by default, so if you were to use a `JPanel` instead of `JFrame`, you wouldn't need to implement it yourself.  Don't call `repaint` from within paint methods, this won't end well (consuming all your CPU cycles for instance). Also consider using the key bindings API over `KeyListener`

Comment: Also you're "breaking the painting chain" as MadProgrammer would call it by not calling the super's paint method in your override.

Comment: Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: `"UPDATE: I have the image in the same directory as the code. I am using a mac and I have tried "image.png", "./image.png", "Users/myStuff/Documents/workspace/Game/src/image.png". Niether of these have worked."` -- then you're definitely using the wrong path. Have you searched on this at all? This has been discussed here and elsewhere to death.

Comment: It should be more like `getClass().getResource("/image.png")` assuming the image is in the default package

Comment: Please check out @MadProgrammer's answer to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13871588/522444). It goes into pretty decent detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Significant issues with your code above...

first and foremost, if your image is with your class files, then don't get it as a File, but rather get it as a resource as MadProg shows (and as most similar questions on this site will tell you):

```
    // get your image as a resource
    URL resource = Game.class.getResource(RESOURCE_PATH);
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        // read in using ImageIO
        img = ImageIO.read(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Next of all, never draw directly within the JFrame and certainly not within its paint method. Instead check out the Swing drawing tutorials and follow their lead: draw within the paintComponent method of a JPanel, but only after calling the super's paintComponent method so that the painting can continue down the line of the painting chain.:

```
// draw within the paintComponent method, not the paint method
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // call the super's method to all painting to chain down the line
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (dbimage != null) {
        g.drawImage(dbimage, imgX, imgY, this);
    }
}
```

I prefer to override the JPanel's getPreferredSize when fixing the sizes of my GUI, something like:

```
// set the preferred size of the main Game JPanel safely 
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }
    return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
}
```

Put all together, something like so *might* work:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    public static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "image.png";
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private BufferedImage dbimage = null;
    private int imgX = 0;
    private int imgY = 0;

    public Game(BufferedImage dbimage) {
        this.dbimage = dbimage;
    }

    // draw within the paintComponent method, not the paint method
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // call the super's method to all painting to chain down the line
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (dbimage != null) {
            g.drawImage(dbimage, imgX, imgY, this);
        }
    }

    // set the preferred size of the main Game JPanel safely 
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // get your image as a resource
        URL resource = Game.class.getResource(RESOURCE_PATH);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            // read in using ImageIO
            img = ImageIO.read(resource);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // pass image into your Game JPanel
        Game mainPanel = new Game(img);

        // pass the JPanel into a JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);  // and display it
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start your Swing GUI in a thread-safe manner
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Next look up Key Bindings to help you to do animation with key strokes with this GUI

Answer (score 1):

I added (copied and pasted) the jpeg I wanted from my computer file onto src folder on IDE then copied and pasted the path/reference to ImageIcon..

```
Image image = new ImageIcon("src/catzilla.jpeg").getImage();
```

and it worked.